# Invoking the hover preview from code

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

Is there anyway to invoke the windows preview effect (the one you get when you hover over the icon screenshot in the taskbar)? Notice how the other windows are made transparent? Is there an API to invoke that?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a question from a while ago. I found a snippet that works. You can find it in use at [InteropAndHelpers](https://github.com/betsegaw/windowwalker/blob/master/Window%20Walker/Window%20Walker/Components/InteropAndHelpers.cs) file in the windowwalker project over at Github.

Answer (score 0):

[This sounds like precisely your problem.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/27/10081263.aspx) The answer seems to be "It's purposely impossible and you should feel bad for wanting to do that."